# How to use Visual Studio C++ Compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I recently installed Visual Studio 2013. I can create a new project (Visual C++), but the error I have to come across is that I cannot run the app. Here is the code that I'm trying to run on Visual Studio 2013.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

I am sure this code would run, and will output **hello world**, but in Visual Studio it gives me issues, saying:

> Values cannot be null,
>   Parameter name: solutionDirectory.

What am I missing here?

Here is an image for this:

[image]

Comment: Move the cursor to the line that you have a return on. Press f9 to set a breakpoint. Then press F5 to debug your program. Your output will be in the black window that pops up.

Comment: 1) Why are you using notepad to write the code? 2) How are you bringing that file into your project?

Comment: @drescherjm, same! Unexpected error detected. and the same thing in front of it..

Comment: @BobbyDigital, this time the file was written in Visual Studio..it wasn't written in Notepad, I created the file from New file --> Visual C++ and then i wrote this code..and still getting the error ..

Comment: When you start a new project (c++) go to your solution explorer and add a new file to the source directory.; then try it again. If you open a file, say, from your document folder vs won't run it. I think this might be the behavior you're experiencing although a little different. It seems like you're creating the file appropriately but it isn't tied to your project in any way.

Comment: Switch the item in the combo box to Build to look at the compiler warnings / errors. You are not doing unit testing.

Comment: What kind of project did you create? It looks like it might be trying to run unit tests.  You want to create a new Visual C++ Win32 Console application.

Comment: @BobbyDigital you might be right in this aspect as I am having this file only..I will create a new project and a new file there :)

Comment: Trying to learn how to program using VisualStudio by just banging around with it is like trying to learn how to fly to the moon by just banging on the controls in a space shuttle.  Time to get a good book and start taking this seriously.

Comment: You're right @JohnDibling, I will try keeping your advice in my mind :) Thanks..

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In Visual Studio, you can't just open a `.cpp` file and expect it to run. You must create a project first, or open the .cpp in some existing project.

In your case, there is no project, so there is no **project to build**.

Go to `File --> New --> Project --> Visual C++ --> Win32 Console Application`. You can uncheck "create a directory for solution". On the next page, be sure to check "Empty project".

Then, You can add `.cpp` files you created outside the Visual Studio by right clicking in the `Solution explorer` on folder icon "Source" and Add->Existing Item.

Obviously You can create new .cpp this way too (Add --> New). The .cpp file will be created in your project directory.

Then you can press ctrl+F5 to compile without debugging and can see output on console window.

Answer (score -2):

You may be forgetting something. Before `#include <iostream>`, write `#include <stdafx.h>` and maybe that will help. Then, when you are done writing, click test, than click output from build, then when it is done processing/compiling, press Ctrl+F5 to open the Command Prompt and it should have the output and "press any key to continue."